# Some quantities which definitions are (somehow) similar to the classical Divergence

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, ds.dynamical-systems, riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Motivated by   classical  formulas $L_{X}=d\circ i_{X}+i_{X}\circ d$  and  $L_{X} \Omega=Div(X)  \Omega$  and  the  essential role of the diff operator $d$ in definition of divergence, we define  some  quantities, say $\overline{Div}$, based on the  adjoint operator $d^{*}=\pm *d*$, where $*$  is  the  Hodge star operator.

In this way our  main question is that:

> What are  some   geometric or physical interpretations  for $\overline{Div}$? What are some calculus  identities for this  quantity?In particular is it true  that for  a  closed  manifold $M$, with volum  form  $\Omega$, we  have $\int_{M} \overline{Div}(X)\Omega=0$?
>
> Moreover what is the dynamical interpretation of  $\overline{Div}(X)=0$. This is motivated by classical case: If $Div(X)=0$ then $X$  has  no  an attractor, since the flow  of  $X$ generates a one parameter family of  volume preserving  diffeomorphisms. So we ask: Is there a vector field $X$  which has a compact attractor invariant set but $\overline{Div}(X)$  is identically zero?

1. For a vector  field  $X$ on  a   $2$  dimensional  surface with  volum form $\Omega$ define:

$$\overline{Div}(X)=(i_{X}\circ d^{*}+d^{*}\circ i_{X})(\Omega)$$

2. A  vector  field  $X$ on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$  defines a one  form $\alpha$.  Now   $\overline{Div}(X)$  is  defined as a  unique  function with  $$\alpha \wedge d^{*}(\Omega)=\overline{Div}(X). \Omega    $$
3. For  a  symplectic  manifold  $(M,\omega)$,  $\overline{Div}$  is  the  unique  function with  $$  (i_{X}\circ d^{*}+d^{*}\circ i_{X})(\Omega)\wedge \omega=\overline{Div}(X).\Omega$$    where  $\Omega$ is  the  corresponding  volume form.

Comment: $d^*$ involves a (pseudo-)Riemannian metric. Whereas $d$ is invariant under pullback by all mappings, in particular under diffeomorphisms, and commutes with with infinitesimal diffeomorphisms $L_X$, $d^*$ is only invariant under isometries of the Riemannian metric used. So the integral in your main question only vanishes for Killing vector fields $X$, in general.

Comment: @PeterMichor  thank you very much for your interesting comment.

Answer (score 2):

The divergence operator is simply the exterior derivative operator acting on $(n-1)$-forms, and the divergence theorem is Stokes theorem. This can be seen by just writing everything in local coordinates. Any other version is just using an additional geometric structure to identify an $(n-1)$-form with a vector field or 1-form.